# opcache causing errors: Allowed memory size, and malloc: *** error for object 0x10b4cbaf8: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

Since I installed opcache I am getting these errors:

```
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:02 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4485046248 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:13 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4484571720 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
httpd(33061,0x7fff790d0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b4cbaf8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:31 2015] [notice] child pid 33061 exit signal Abort trap (6)
httpd(33063,0x7fff790d0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b4cbaf8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:32 2015] [notice] child pid 33063 exit signal Abort trap (6)
httpd(33064,0x7fff790d0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b4cbaf8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:33 2015] [notice] child pid 33064 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Thu Jun 04 17:31:34 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4485049952 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I am using Zend Server with Apache.

PHP Version 5.4.21

Here are my conf:

```
[opcache]
zend_extension="/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/opcache.so"
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

When I try to reload my phpinfo.php page it is blank.

What is causing this problem and what did I forget or need to do?